# Как получить ответ из node.js в консоль

Tags: c#, node.js, cmd

есть такой код. как получить ответ из node в консольное приложение

код JS

```
const exe = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs');

var result = exe.spawn('cryptcp.exe', ['-verify', '45.jpg.sig', '45.jpg'], {});


result.stdout.on('data', function (data) { 
    var r = data.toString().toLowerCase();
    if (r.indexOf('do you want to use this certificate') > -1) {
        result.stdin.write('N');
    }
});


result.stderr.on('data', function (data) { 
    process.stdout.write(data.toString()); 
});

result.on('close', function (code) { 
    fs.exists('45.jpg', (res) => {
        if (res) {
            process.exit(0)
        } else {
            process.exit(1)
        }
    });
});

result.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
})
```

c#

```
Process proc = new Process();
                    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"jsx/verify.js";
                    proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
                    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "node.exe";
                    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

                    proc.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
                    };

                    proc.Exited += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("awd"); 


                    proc.Start();
```

как видно пробывал так

```
process.exit(0)
```

Comment: ну а что не работает то?

Comment: proc.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
                    }; не выводит ни чего

Comment: ну а breakpoint там срабатывает?

Comment: а ждать когда процесс закончится кто будет? Полистайте [примерчик в доках](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived?view=netframework-4.7.2)